# How do I get GRUB2 to boot an ISO file like USB/CD?

Tags: grub2

How do I get GRUB2 to boot an ISO file and get it to display the initial menu screen (like it does when booting an USB/CD via the BIOS) ?

For example, the following menu definition ("/etc/grub.d/40_custom"):

```
menuentry 'CentOS-8.3.2011-x86_64-dvd1.iso' {
    set root=(hd0,msdos3)
    set isofile=/CentOS-8.3.2011-x86_64-dvd1.iso
    set cdlabel=CentOS-8.3.2011-x86_64-dvd
    loopback loop $isofile
    linux (loop)/isolinux/vmlinuz inst.stage2=hd:LABEL=$cdlabel iso-scan/filename=$isofile
    initrd (loop)/isolinux/initrd.img
}
```

boots into:

[image]

But I want GRUB2 to boot into:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use `memdisk` from `syslinux` for this.   I don't know what package that is in on Centos, but on Debian, it's in package `syslinux-common`.  The package probably has a similar name on Centos.

I also use the script below to automatically generate entries for all `.iso` and `.img` files found in `/boot/memdisk/`, whenever `update-grub` is run.

On non-debian systems, you'd run`grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` instead of `update-grub` - update-grub is just a simple wrapper around grub-mkconfig.

On my systems, I've saved the following as `/etc/grub.d/42-memdisk`, and made it executable with `chmod +x`.  The number at the start of the filename affects the order that it is executed.  `grub-mkconfig` runs scripts in `/etc/grub.d/` in sorted order.  On my system, it's the last script executed so the `memdisk` entries are at the bottom of the grub menu.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -e

IMAGES=/boot/images
. /usr/lib/grub/grub-mkconfig_lib
if test -e /boot/memdisk ; then
  echo "Found memdisk: $MEMDISKPATH" >&2
  MEMDISKPATH="$( make_system_path_relative_to_its_root "/boot/memdisk" )"

  find "$IMAGES" -name '*.img' -o -name '*.iso' | sort | 
  while read image ; do
      IMAGEPATH="$( make_system_path_relative_to_its_root "$image" )"
      echo "Found image: $IMAGEPATH" >&2
      cat << EOF
menuentry "Bootable image: $(basename $IMAGEPATH | sed -E -e 's/\.(img|iso)$//i')" {
EOF
      prepare_grub_to_access_device ${GRUB_DEVICE_BOOT} | sed -e 's/^/\t/'
      cat << EOF
        linux16 $MEMDISKPATH bigraw
        initrd16 $IMAGEPATH
}
EOF
  done
fi
```